# Multiple IDs in Jquery for image carousel not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a jquery code for an image carousel, but I have multiple carousel id's that I want to run through the code. #myCarousel works beautifully, but #historyCarousel doesn't work at all.

I'm very new to JS, so I'm also not sure how to change this to a class if needed (how do I need to edit the code besides replacing # with . ?)

This is the code I have right now - only #myCarousel is working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#myCarousel,#historyCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
    });

    $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

    //Handles the carousel thumbnails
   $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
        var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
        var id = parseInt(id);
        $('#myCarousel,#historyCarousel').carousel(id);
    });


    // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
    $('#myCarousel,#historyCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
             var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
            $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
    });
```

});

Answer (score 2):

The carousel constructor (not sure what you're using) is probably expecting an element (or list with a single item) instead of selection list.  Try this in an each loop:

```
$('#myCarousel,#historyCarousel').each(function(idx, el){
    $(el).carousel({ interval: 5000 });
});
```